# Drawable item don't show up

Tags: java, android

I just started Android development and working on a little app related to google maps api. Am using the Google Map View for this and following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)..
I've created a custom itemizedOverlay, which has a constructor like this(as told in the tutorial) -

```
public pujaItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    mContext = context;
}
```

I have a image file named `sprite.png` in the `res/drawable/` forder. And here is my onCreate() function -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sprite);
        pujaItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new pujaItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    }
```

The problem is, The image named sprite doesn't show up on the map.
One this I'd like to mention is that, according to the tutorial, they added a second paramete to the constructor of the custom itemizedOverlay of the class Context. But in their example, when they called that overlay, they provided only one parameter(check the tutorial page), like -
`HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);`
Eclipse showed an obvious error in this line, so I added the second parameter as `this` to provide the current context. Am I doing it right here?
***Update***:
The image in question is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3797952/sprite.png).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my overlays on a mapview not shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357623/why-are-my-overlays-on-a-mapview-not-shown). If any mod is around, close this question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357623/why-are-my-overlays-on-a-mapview-not-shown). It seems that if the mapview doesn't know how to align the image it won't show it at all.